# Triangle vector problem

Tags: vectors, triangles, vector-fields

[image]

I consider how to draw this because I have no idea with the Origin,
is the 3.1 part we can solve with :

> triangle QAB: triangle QBC so,
> AQ : QC = 2:3 ?

But I can't solve the 3.2 part, can anyone show the picture of the triangle and steps to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, just draw three points somewhere in the first quadrant, and call them $ABC$. Now locate the centroid of the triangle, let's call it $M$. Areas of triangles $ABM$, $BCM$, and $CAM$ are all equal. So your point $P$ is farther from $AC$ then $M$, such as the area of $PCA$ is half of the area of the triangle $ABC$. Don't worry if your figure is slightly off.